# Having trouble in getting input from user in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a method which check if the file exists, If the file does not exist then it should call another method which prompts the questions. Below is the sample code.

```
def readFile1()
      flag = false

      begin
        @ssh.exec!("cd #{@@home_dir}")

        puts "\nChecking if file exists on #{@hostname}\n"

        if @ssh.exec!("sh -c '[ -f "#{file_name}" ]; echo $?'").to_i == 0
             flag = true
             puts "File exists on #{@hostname}"

             display()

       else
              puts "File does not exist. Please answer following questions."
              prompt()
       end

     rescue => e
          puts "readFile1 failed... #{e}"
     end

     return exists

end

def prompt()
        puts "\nDo you want to enter the new file location? [y/n]"
        ans = gets.chomp
        puts "New location is #{ans}"
end
```

When I am calling `readFile` method, if the file does not exists, it prints `Do you want to enter the new file location? [y/n]` and does not wait for the user to enter the value but immediately prints the `rescue` block and quits. Below is the Output if file does not exists.

```
Checking if file exists on LNXAPP
File does not exist. Please answer following questions.
Do you want to enter the new file location? [y/n]
readFile1 failed... No such file or directory - LNXAPP
```

I want the user to enter the values for the questions but it's not happening.Need help in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not ideal.

You should check if the file exists via:

```
if File.exist? location_of_your_file_goes_here
```

The begin/rescue is then not required, because
you already check before whether the file exists.

Also two spaces should be better than one tab,
at least when you display on a site such as here.

Reason is simple - it makes your code easier
to read for others.

You also don't need the flag variable if I am
right - try to omit it and use solely File.exist?
there.

Also you wrote:

"When I am calling readFile method"

But you have no method called readFile().

Your method is called readFile1().

I know that you probably know this too, but
you must be very specific so that the ruby
parser understands precisely what you mean,
and that what you describe with words also
matches to the code you use.

Another issue I see with your code is that
you do this:

```
return exists
```

but what is "exists" here? A variable?
A method? It has not been defined elsewhere
in your code.

Try to make your code as simple and as logical
as possible.